# Insert and delete from dictionary in a for loop -- optimal method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
{attribute_1 : True,
 attribute_2 : False,
 attribute_3 : 'foo', # Can be one of multiple text options here
 attribute_4 : 5,}    # Can be one of multiple numerical options here
```

I need to convert it so that every value is a boolean, thus giving:

```
{attribute_1 : True,
 attribute_2 : False,
 attribute_3_foo : True,
 attribute_4_5 : True}
```

(one-hot encoding for machine learning, in case anyone cares why I'm doing such an odd thing.  Will process many, many such dictionaries...).

A working solution I have found is to do a for loop through the dict to hunt for non-boolean vals and (1) create new entries, then (2) delete anything with non-boolean key.  That's fine, but it seems inelegant and memory inefficient as my list is a new object in memory.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
# List loop to insert ('k,v in dict' won't let you add/delete items)
for x in list(sub_d.items()):
    if type(x[1]) is not bool:
        sub_d[x[0]+'_'+ str(x[1])] = True
        del sub_d[x[0]]
```

PS. List comprehensions don't work, as I can't find a way to feed in a sufficiently complex operation to do the work.  Plus I don't think they would have any efficiency gains over the my current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use a `dict` comprehension:

```
d = {k if isinstance(v, bool) else '{}_{}'.format(k, v): bool(v) 
     for k, v in d.items()} 

{'attribute_1': True,
 'attribute_2': False,
 'attribute_3_foo': True,
 'attribute_4_5': True}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## List loop to insert ('k,v in dict' won't let you add/delete items)
>
> ```
> for x in list(sub_d.items()):
>
>    if type(x[1]) is not bool:
>
>        sub_d[x[0]+'_'+ str(x[1])] = True
>
>        del sub_d[x[0]]
> ```

Why not just:

```
for x in dic:
  if type(x) is not bool:
    dic[x] = True
```

There is no reason to delete the entries, and this will run in O(n) time, as a `dic` is a hashtable.

Comment: Good question. I create+delete because items like `attribute_3 : 'foo'` can also be  `attribute_3 : 'bar'` (etc...)  and I need the one-hot encoding to identify the various text options for attribute_3 as different things.  I'll edit the original Q to make this clearer

Comment: @Mark_Anderson I still think there is no reason to delete the entries, as you can just set them to a different value. And I am confused still. Are we saying that we want `False` for `foo` and `True` for `bar`, or are we just setting them all to `True`? That is how I interpreted the original problem.

Comment: My goals are a bit odd -- are you familiar with one-hot encoding?  I am trying to assign a boolean for every possible bit of information in the dictionary for every one of the many dictionaries I receive.  So if this was about cars, I might have `{engine: 'V8'}` or `{engine: 'V12'}` in different dictionaries.  I want to get `{engine_V8: True}` or `{engine_V12:True}` here, and thus I delete the `{engine:'somestring'}` after I'm done

Comment: Later a function compiles the dictionaries into a giant table of booleans with T/F for columns `engine_V8 `,`engine_V12` etc.... inserting false wherever a dictionary has no entry.

Comment: @Mark_Anderson okay, I think I see what is going on. Thank you for taking the time to explain it. My understanding is that we have to delete `item` from the `origDic` (if you will), once we have gone through all `otherDics` to see if `itemVariant` exists and setting them to `True`, we then delete `item` from `origDic`. Is this right?

Comment: Close, I don't come back to `origDict` after looking at `otherDicts`.  I just do this clean and delete within `origDict`, then a summary function later looks at and compiles all the possible unique entries from `origDic` and many `otherDicts` to make the table --- that summary is why I delete the items (I don't want it trying to interpret `engine: 'something'`, I've done that interpretation already by making the booleans from the various options that `something` could be).